# Snap window to appear adjacent to other tabs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

In below screenshot "package explorer" overlays "servers" tab. How can I position it so that it appears adjacent to "Server" tab instead of overlaying it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've "detached" the Package Explorer panel into a separate top-level window. You need to drag its tab back into the main container window and Eclipse will show guidelines as you drag it around to indicate where it will be placed when you release the drag click (drop it).

Answer (score 0):

Dragging the entire tab did not work for me. I needed to hover the mouse pointer of the text for the tab in question and drag it to the new location.

For example hover the pointer over the "JUnit" text within the tab before dragging :

[image]